scssTask Errored during Gulp-Sass execution
I'm just starting out with Gulp via VS Code but I can't seem to get it working.
Here is my Gulp file:
// Initialize modules
const { src, dest, watch, series } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const terser = require('gulp-terser');
const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Use dart-sass for @use
//sass.compiler = require('dart-sass');

// Sass Task
function scssTask() {
  return src('app/scss/style.scss', { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
    .pipe(dest('dist', { sourcemaps: '.' }));
}

// JavaScript Task
function jsTask() {
  return src('app/js/script.js', { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(babel({ presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] }))
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(dest('dist', { sourcemaps: '.' }));
}

// Browsersync
function browserSyncServe(cb) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: '.',
    },
    notify: {
      styles: {
        top: 'auto',
        bottom: '0',
      },
    },
  });
  cb();
}
function browserSyncReload(cb) {
  browsersync.reload();
  cb();
}

// Watch Task
function watchTask() {
  watch('*.html', browserSyncReload);
  watch(
    ['app/scss/**/*.scss', 'app/**/*.js'],
    series(scssTask, jsTask, browserSyncReload)
  );
}

// Default Gulp Task
exports.default = series(scssTask, jsTask, browserSyncServe, watchTask);

// Build Gulp Task
exports.build = series(scssTask, jsTask);

When I run it I get the following error:
PS C:\Users\xyz\Documents\GitHub\fem-social-dklt-toggle> gulp
[16:25:08] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\GitHub\fem-social-dklt-toggle\gulpfile.js
[16:25:08] Starting 'default'...
[16:25:08] Starting 'scssTask'...
[16:25:09] 'scssTask' errored after 1.05 s
[16:25:09] Error: File not found with singular glob: C:/Users/xyz/Documents/GitHub/fem-social-dklt-toggle/app/scss/style.scss (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
    at C:\Users\xyz\Documents\GitHub\fem-social-dklt-toggle\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:343:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EventEmitter.onEnd (C:\Users\xyz\Documents\GitHub\fem-social-dklt-toggle\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:340:11)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:28)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:551:15)
    at queue.drain (C:\Users\xyz\Documents\GitHub\fem-social-dklt-toggle\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:35:8)
    at Task.release (C:\Users\xyz\Documents\GitHub\fem-social-dklt-toggle\node_modules\fastq\queue.js:179:12)
    at worked (C:\Users\xyz\Documents\GitHub\fem-social-dklt-toggle\node_modules\fastq\queue.js:223:10)
    at onStat (C:\Users\xyz\Documents\GitHub\fem-social-dklt-toggle\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:106:16)
[16:25:09] 'default' errored after 1.06 s


I have used Dart Sass supports @use and other recent features of Sass and run this command $ npm install dart-sass --save-dev. I have also try deleted the node modules files and package json file and reinstall using npm i and yet still not working.
